# Programs that lock the computer

Tags: javascript, css, software-design

At my school we have started using a new typing software for our exams. This software is called Digiexam: https://www.digiexam.se/en/ When Digiexam is started the computer freezes so that the program window won't be shut down until the essay is handed in. As I have understood most of the code is written in css and javascript. To my question: How can you freeze the computer like this using code?

Comment: Probably not with just CSS and JS. And if so, it's exploiting some kind of hack.

Comment: don't confuse the html/css in user interface with the full installed program

Comment: How could I access the full installed program files?

Comment: @SamuelTober If it's not open source, you can't unless you've got some serious reverse engineering skills.

Answer (score 2):

Digiexam has to install a client application/service on the pc/mac that runs the software.  It probably has a web application that works in tandem with the installed application. So to answer your question - no you can't freeze the computer with just css and javascript.  :-)

https://digiexam.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201634922-Installation-guide-Windows